# How to re-iterate calculation in PHP with different variables each time?

Tags: php

I have written a code to carry out a calculation using my formula, however I am having difficulty getting code to recalculate using my formula with different variables each time. Instead it is using the same variable. I would like each time it re-ran to use one of the randomly selected variable in the formula. Please see the code below. Note I am a beginner.

`    
     PIIP Calculations

```
  $PIIPCount = 3 ;

  $Area = array(1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000) ;
  $Height = array(100, 150, 200, 250, 250) ;
  $Poro = array(0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20) ;
  $SatCon = array(0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08) ;
  $OilVolFac = array(1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2) ;

  //$AreaCount = count($Area);
  $AreaCount = $PIIPCount ;

  for ($i = 0; $i < $AreaCount ; $i++ ) {
    $RandA = $Area[array_rand($Area)];
    print "<li> $RandA <li>";
   }

   //$HeightCount = count($Height);
   $HeightCount = $PIIPCount ;

   for ($j = 0; $j < $HeightCount ; $j++ ) {
    $RandH = $Height[array_rand($Height)];
    print "<li> $RandH <li>";
   }

   // $PoroCount = count($Poro);
  $PoroCount = $PIIPCount ;

  for ($k = 0; $k < $PoroCount ; $k++ ) {
    $RandP = $Poro[array_rand($Poro)];
    print "<li> $RandP <li>";
   }

   // $SatConCount = count($SatCon);
   $SatConCount = $PIIPCount ;

    for ($l = 0; $l < $SatConCount ; $l++ ) {
     $RandS = $SatCon[array_rand($SatCon)];
     print "<li> $RandS <li>";
    }

     // $OilVolFacCount = count($OilVolFac);
     $OilVolFacCount = $PIIPCount ;

      for ($m = 0; $m < $PoroCount ; $m++ ) {
      $RandO = $OilVolFac[array_rand($OilVolFac)];
       print "<li> $RandO <li>";
       }

        $arrayA = array($RandA) ;
        print '<br $arrayA[0] />' ;
        $arrayA1 = $arrayA[0] ;
        print $arrayA1 ;

        $arrayH = array($RandH) ;
        print '<br $arrayH[0] />' ;
        $arrayH1 = $arrayH[0] ;
        print $arrayH1 ;

        $arrayP = array($RandP) ;
        print '<br $arrayP[0] />' ;
        $arrayP1 = $arrayP[0] ;
        print $arrayP1 ;

        $arrayS = array($RandS) ;
        print '<br $arrayS[0] />' ;
        $arrayS1 = $arrayS[0] ;
        print $arrayS1 ;

       $arrayO = array($RandO) ;
       print '<br $arrayO[0]  />' ;
       $arrayO1 = $arrayO[0];  
       print '<br $arrayO1 />';

       $Sample = array(array($RandA), array($RandH), array($RandP), array($RandS),       `enter code her`array($RandO));
      print'<br $Sample[3][1] >' ;


      for ( $n = 0 ; $n < $PIIPCount; $n++) {
      $PIIPCalc = (($arrayA1*$arrayH1*$arrayP1)*(1-$arrayS1)/$arrayO1) ;
       print  round($PIIPCalc).  " " ;
       }

       ?>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is your friend...

Answer (score 1):

Variables are placeholders in an algorithm. You don't "run an algorithm with different variables", that would mean that you change the algorithm; no, you run an algorithm with *different **values** for its variables*.

It's rather unclear what variables you're trying to change here, but consider this:

```
function myAlgorithm($value) {
    // do something
    return $result;
}

echo myAlgorithm('foo');
echo myAlgorithm('bar');
echo myAlgorithm('baz');
```

The algorithm and the variables in `myAlgorithm` do not change, but you're running the same algorithm with different input values. I believe this is what you want; learn about [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

You can do essentially the same with loops:

```
foreach (array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') as $value) {
    // do something
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm +1'ing this because while my answer will get it done, if it is something like this that should be run multiple times, it really should be wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the values in the variables of your bottom for loop where you are doing the calculation. Also as you are looping over the arrays at the top getting random values, you are just overwriting the value of your `$Rand{whatever}` variable. This whole thing could be done with a single loop like:

```
<?php
$PIIPCount = 3 ;

$Area = array(1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000) ;
$Height = array(100, 150, 200, 250, 250) ;
$Poro = array(0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20) ;
$SatCon = array(0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08) ;
$OilVolFac = array(1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2) ;

//loop for count of PIIPCount
for($i=0; $i<$PIIPCount; $i++){
    //get one value from each array at random and save it on our blank arrays
    $randA = $Area[array_rand($Area)];
    $randH = $Height[array_rand($Height)];
    $randP = $Poro[array_rand($Poro)];
    $randS = $SatCon[array_rand($SatCon)];
    $randO = $OilVolFac[array_rand($OilVolFac)];

    $PIIPCalc = (($randA*$randH*$randP)*(1-$randS)/$randO) ;
    print "(($randA*$randH*$randP)*(1-$randS)/$randO) = ";
    print  round($PIIPCalc).  "<br>" ;
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/FddttW

On each iteration of the for loop I'm getting new random values into my $rand variables and those are being used in the formula.

Comment: Thanks everyone for you comments. Jonathan thanks a lot your code above, does what I was trying to do. Much appreciated.